# A binding to play.api.db.DBApi was already configured, evolutions and injector error with play-slick

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, slick

I want to introduce slick to my play project, so I add the following dependencies to build.sbt:

```
"com.typesafe.play"          %% "play-slick"               % "1.0.1"     withSources(),
  "com.typesafe.play"          %% "play-slick-evolutions"    % "1.0.1"     withSources(),
```

Then, when I run an integration spec for controller I got following exception both on Intellij IDE and command line activator test. After Google I found the solution: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlickFAQ#A-binding-to-play.api.db.DBApi-was-already-configured

After I removed the jdbc dependency, the integration spec passed when I using the command line, however I still got the same error when I run the test on Intellij IDE as following error:
Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

```
1) A binding to play.api.db.DBApi was already configured at play.api.db.DBModule.bindings(DBModule.scala:25):
Binding(interface play.api.db.DBApi to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.DBApiProvider)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1).
  at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:15):
Binding(interface play.api.db.DBApi to ConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter) in interface javax.inject.Singleton) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

1 error
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) A binding to play.api.db.DBApi was already configured at play.api.db.DBModule.bindings(DBModule.scala:25):
Binding(interface play.api.db.DBApi to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.DBApiProvider)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1).
  at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:15):
Binding(interface play.api.db.DBApi to ConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter) in interface javax.inject.Singleton) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
    at play.api.test.FakeApplication.<init>(Fakes.scala:216)
    at org.scalatestplus.play.OneServerPerSuite$class.app(OneServerPerSuite.scala:152)
```

Answer (score 61):

If you are like me, you have something like this in your build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.37",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.1.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.1.1"
)
```

remove jdbc

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  //jdbc, //<<---- this one here
  cache,
```

Comment: Actually, there is an official [FAQ](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlickFAQ#A-binding-to-play.api.db.DBApi-was-already-configured) describing this problem.

Comment: Also check for `anorm` or anything else that uses the database :)

Answer (score 6):

You have probably added dependency to jdbc which doesn't make sense if you use slick for it. Remove it and it will work.