# How to mix Slick and JDBC in the same Play Framework project?

Tags: playframework, slick-3.0, playframework-2.6

I'd like to mix regular JDBC into my Play Framework project using Slick.  I've ran into a few hurdles.  Directly adding the `jdbc` dependency to my project yields this error from this question

[A binding to play.api.db.DBApi was already configured, evolutions and injector error with play-slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004303/a-binding-to-play-api-db-dbapi-was-already-configured-evolutions-and-injector-e)

removing the `jdbc` dependency means I cannot use the `play.api.db.Database` class and yields this error `Play error on startup: No implementation for play.api.db.Database was bound`

So how can I use regular jdbc and sql queries without slick in the same project.

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42416309/1908265